# How can I check validation loss within an epoch in tensorflow callback?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am running Tensorflow 2.0 and training a model on 2 GPUs. It takes just over 3,000 batches per epoch and each epoch takes just under an hour. After each epoch, I can see the validation loss, but what I want is to be able to check the validation loss more frequently, say after every 200 batches.

I was thinking I would do something like this:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback

class TrackValidationLoss(Callback):
    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        if (batch % 200 == 0):
            train_loss = logs['loss']
            val_loss = # How can I get validation loss here?

            # Do something with validation loss here
```

This is the part I am struggling with. I know I can get it at the end of an epoch but I would like to get it within an epoch to see in a more detailed way how the model trains over time.

Comment: ```val_loss = logs['val_loss']```?

Comment: `'val_loss'` is only a valid key for the `on_epoch_end()` callback method

Comment: Similar unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58670424/how-to-record-training-and-validation-loss-after-each-batch-rather-than-epoch-in).